# how to auto set true ( auto save when capture) with image picker in flutter

Tags: flutter, imagepicker

I'm working with image picker then I always want to save the image that i click captured
but dont know how to set it, we have to press the right button to save it, is there any way to reduce the progress while we use use it( not to click multiple time ? )[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ga4us.jpg)
try to search from youtube and some other source but didnt find anything

Comment: if you want only camera image then simply use Camera Package : https://pub.dev/packages/camera

Comment: I'm currently use the watermark in setting of device too.
if use that i have to take another step to convert the image then add watermark in there. take long time then I suppose